# How to post or share my rails application events on Facebook ,Twitter and Linkedin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, linked-list

Hi i  want to share my rails application question,answers,comments etc with facebook ,twitter and linkedin.I am using rails 3.2.0.

Is there only one gem exist to do the stuff.

If not which gems you will recommends i have already used theses gems for login

```
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-twitter
  omniauth-linkedin
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is awesome and does not require any gem.

https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.UBZkUTQgeZw

You need to add the given script to your website and you can also customize the widget.